# Contour plot in Xmgrace

Tags: contour, xmgrace

[image]I have a data file containing 3 columns. Now I want to have a contour plot with xmgrace as I use xmgrace mostly. But somehow, I am unable to do draw it now. Can anyone help me a bit? Thanks in advance.
The data is in format shown below:

3.24 4.78 0.015776
3.24 4.80 0.011777
3.24 4.82 0.00986
3.24 4.84 0.010185
3.24 4.86 0.012515
3.26 4.78 0.009244
3.26 4.80 0.006368
3.26 4.82 0.005792
3.26 4.84 0.007121
3.26 4.86 0.010361
3.28 4.78 0.004666
3.28 4.80 0.0028
3.28 4.82 0.003017
3.28 4.84 0.005285
3.28 4.86 0.0095
3.30 4.78 0.001295
3.30 4.80 0.000557
3.30 4.82 0.001924
3.30 4.84 0.005266
3.30 4.86 0.010401
3.32 4.78 0
3.32 4.80 0.000233
3.32 4.82 0.002508
3.32 4.84 0.006666
3.32 4.86 0.012515
3.34 4.70 0.012943
3.34 4.72 0.006904
3.34 4.74 0.002791
3.34 4.76 0.000662
3.36 4.70 0.011024
3.36 4.72 0.005998
3.36 4.74 0.003063
3.36 4.76 0.001814
3.38 4.70 0.011203
3.38 4.72 0.007077
3.38 4.74 0.004755
3.38 4.76 0.004188
3.40 4.70 0.01263
3.40 4.72 0.009182
3.40 4.74 0.007685
3.40 4.76 0.007985

The final curve should be like as shown in the attachment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick Google search reveals that xmgrace (a.k.a. Grace) [does not support contour plots](http://plasma-gate.weizmann.ac.il/Grace/doc/FAQ.html#ss10.3)

There are a wealth of example scripts for contour plots using [gnuplot](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/contours.html), [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/contour_demo.html), [Origin](http://wiki.originlab.com/~originla/howto/index.php?title=Tutorial:Contour_Plots_and_Color_Mapping) and many more.

Here is a simple example for gnuplot using your data:
Once you have saved your data as the 3-column data file `data.dat` save the following as a script file:

```
set parametric
set contour base
set view 0,0,1
unset surface
unset key
unset ztics
set dgrid3d
set title "Simple contour plot example" 
set xlabel "X" 
set ylabel "Y" 
set cntrparam levels 10
splot "data.dat" using 1:2:3 with line
```

and from the UNIX command line call `gnuplot -persist scriptfile`.
This gives the following output: 
[image]

So, it looks like you didn't use xmgrace, you used gnuplot, and that's why you can't work out how to remake the original plot in xmgrace again!

Comment: Many thanks, you're right I didn't try with xmgrace. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can plot contour lines with GraceGtk, a fork of Grace that also adds Undo functionality.

Currently, this software is available at https://sourceforge.net/projects/gracegtk/.

This answer is valid as long as GraceGtk is available for download somewhere in the Internet.

Contour plots and undo are planned features for future releases of Grace.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please quote the most important parts of the link, in case the page changes or permanently goes offline.